# Why phone numbers in MySQL database are being truncated

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a database table in mySQL of which two column names are "landPhone" and "mobilePhone" to store phone numbers (in the format of: 123-456-8000 for land and 098-765-6601 for mobile). These two columns' data type are set to VARCHAR(30). The data have been inserted in the table. But after SQL query, I found the phone numbers have been truncated. It shows (above two data for example) only first 3 digits (123) for landPhone and only first 2 digits after removing the leading '0' (98) for mobilePhone.

Why this is happening ?

Comment: What code are you using to INSERT those values?

Comment: check again in your database table that you have taken the datatype of the columns varchar or int because if your datatype is varchar then it must be insert as string.

Comment: check the structure of your table. your question sounds as if somehow both fields are treated as int.

Comment: what is sql code you are using. so that we can give you actual answer

Comment: Here's my recommendations for phone-number tables - 1) Store the 'destination' country code. 2) If possible, remove all formatting, and apply during display (among other things, this makes exporting for robo-dialing easier) 3) Phone numbers are a string of 15 digits (at most - I'm a little fuzzy on whether that includes the country code) - you don't need 30.  4) Store each phone on it's own row (this will let customers store multiple lines easily), with a code for 'type' (fk reference to other table)

Answer (score 8):

Phone numbers are not actually *numbers*; they are strings that happen to contain digits (and, in your case, dashes).  If you try to interpret one as a number, two things typically happen:

- Leading zeros are forgotten.
- Everything from the first non-digit to the end of the string is stripped off.

That sounds exactly like the result you're describing.  Even if you end up stuffing the result into a string field, it's too late -- the data has already been corrupted.

Make sure you're not treating phone numbers as integers at any point in the process.

Comment: But the two columns are `varchar(30)`.

Comment: @muistooshort: But somewhere along the way, they are being interpreted as integers -- that'd explain why the leading 0, and everything after and including the first non-digit, are stripped off.

Comment: yes i think so that he is actually using them as integer or columns has integer.

Comment: Which is why we need to know what code is being used to insert those values before a useful answer can be given.

Answer (score 6):

You must use

```
insert into sample values('123-456-8000', '098-765-6601' )
```

instead of

```
insert into sample values(123-456-8000, 098-765-6601 )
```

see this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6027d8/1).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your solution. As cHao suspected, it was me who did the mistake. When I first time created the table, I declared the datatype of the phone columns as INT, later I corrected them to VARCHAR().

When I dropped the table and inserted the same data to the new table, it is working fine.

> ***That sounds exactly like the result you're describing. Even if you end up stuffing the result into a string field, it's too late -- the data has already been corrupted. ..cHao***

Question to understand: Why mySQL doesn't override the previous datatype with the new one ?

Comment: It does.  And existing data can be reinterpreted as the type changes.  But any phone "numbers" that were already in the table, and were thus stored as integers, had to be converted -- which tosses out the non-numeric parts -- so they'd be storable in an int column.  Changing the datatype can't cause that lost info to automagically come back, as the original string is long gone.  It'd have to be reinserted or updated.